# Who are these villains in Spider-Man: Freshman Year?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, spider-man, spider-man-freshman-year

Who are these characters in the newly announced Marvel series *Spider-Man: Freshman Year*?

[image: Here's the first look at the #SpiderMan villains in Disney+'s SPIDER-MAN: FRESHMAN YEAR!]

Comment: The Wiki says that [the voice cast](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Freshman_Year) consists of; May Parker, Harry Osborn, Nico Minoru, Amadeus Cho, Norman Osborn, Doctor Strange, Daredevil, Doctor Octopus, Scorpion, Chameleon, Tombstone, Speed Demon, Rhino, Unicorn, Tarantula and Bentley Whitman

Comment: I've taken the liberty of swapping the cropped photo out for the one from [Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/MCU_Direct/status/1550565771465605126). The caption reads "***Here's the first look at the #SpiderMan villains in Disney+'s SPIDER-MAN: FRESHMAN YEAR!***"

Comment: I’m going to go out on a limb and say they’re some villains.

Comment: Does this count as future works?

Comment: @PeterNielsen - Not when it's answerable today.

Comment: Sci-Fi.SE: answering tomorrow's questions, today!

Comment: @Valorum good good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki page for this series](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Freshman_Year) lists the follow characters among the voice cast:

> - To-be-confirmed voice actress as May Parker
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Harry Osborn
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Nico Minoru
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Amadeus Cho
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Norman Osborn
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Stephen Strange/Doctor Strange
> - Charlie Cox as Matt Murdock/Daredevil
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Otto Octavius/Doctor Octopus
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Mac Gargan/Scorpion
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Dimitri Smerdyakov/Chameleon
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Alonzo "Lonnie" Lincoln/Tombstone
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as James Sanders/Speed Demon
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Aleksei Sytsevich/Rhino
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Milos Masaryk/Unicorn
> - To-be-confirmed voice actor as Anton Miguel Rodriquez/Tarantula
> - Paul F. Tompkins as Bentley Whitman

A larger version of the image in your question [was posted on Collider](https://collider.com/spider-man-freshman-year-images-sdcc-disney-plus/), and in that, the characters were all tagged as 'villains', which narrows the field a bit. I've added numbers to the image to help ID everyone.

[image]

So, going off their appearances, the voice cast listed above, and the presumption that they're all villains, I'm 99% confident that character #2 is the [the Scorpion/Mac Gargan](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/MacDonald_Gargan_(Earth-616)), character #5 is [Dr. Octopus/Otto Octavius](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Otto_Octavius_(Earth-616)), and character #9 is [the Chameleon/Dmitri Smerdyakov](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dmitri_Smerdyakov_(Earth-616)).

I'm highly confident about those three, because they have iconic looks, and the way they're drawn and coloured in the above image is near enough a spot-on match to their classic designs. Admittedly, Ock's tentacles aren't visible in the image, but they could be hidden beneath the lab coat (they're pretty short when fully retracted), or perhaps he's just not wearing the harness in this image.

I'd say character #7 is very likely to be [the Rhino/Aleksei Sytsevich](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Aleksei_Sytsevich_(Earth-616)). That's how he looks out of costume (especially when drawn by John Romita Sr. in 1960s issues), and he's only character I've seen in any images associated with the show whose physical build matches that of the comicbook version of the Rhino. Also, he's dressed all in grey, the same colour as the Rhino's costume.

Character #3 bears a strong resemblance to [Tarantula/Maria Vasquez](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maria_Vasquez_(Earth-616)). She wasn't listed among the characters on the Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki page for the show, however, Anton Miguel Rodriquez -- the *original* Tarantula from the comics -- was. I could be mistaken, but I suspect this is a mix-up of some sort, and that Vasquez, rather than Rodriquez, will be the Tarantula on the show. Either that, or Rodriquez has had a pretty dramatic makeover.

I'm less confident about this one than the previous characters I've mentioned, but I'd guess that character number #8 is a redesign of [Speed Demon/James Sanders](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Sanders_(Earth-616)). The colours of his jacket and shirt correspond to those of Speed Demon's costume in the comics, and Speed Demon's mask in the comics has a visor resembling sunglasses as well. He's normally drawn with grey hair out of costume, but this could be a younger version of the character.

Through a process of elimination, I'd guess that character #1 is a redesign of [the Unicorn/Milos Masaryk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Milos_Masaryk_(Earth-616)). That's one of the few villains named on the Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki page for the show that I haven't already covered, the green and orange correspond to the colour scheme of the Unicorn's costume in the comics, and the mask appears to have a protrusion on the forehead resembling the Unicorn's 'Power Horn' in the comics. Not sure of this character's civilian ID though, since they appear to be female in this depiction, and, as far as I know, there isn't a female version in the comics.

A character named 'Butane the Pyromaniac' has been mentioned in various related articles on sites such as [IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/spider-man-freshman-year-arrives-on-disney-in-2024-will-feature-charlie-coxs-daredevil) and [CinemaBlend](https://www.cinemablend.com/superheroes/spider-man/disneys-spider-man-freshman-year-has-revealed-charlie-coxs-daredevil-and-a-ton-of-other-marvel-characters), so I'd guess that that's who character #4 is. As far as I can tell, this isn't an existing character in the comics, so they may've been newly-created for the show. There is an obscure character named '[Butane](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Butane_(Earth-616))' in the comics, but the two characters don't bear much resemblance to one another, and that Butane has nothing to do with Spider-Man. Since I don't believe 'Butane the Pyromaniac' exists in the comics, I couldn't tell you what their real name is.

I'm not yet confident enough to guess at who character #6 is. She could potentially be a newly-created character, as I suspect 'Butane the Pyromaniac' is, but I'll do some more digging and update this answer if I think I've IDed them, assuming someone else doesn't beat me to it. In the meantime, here's my list as it currently stands:

1. The Unicorn/???
2. The Scorpion/Mac Gargan
3. Tarantula/Maria Vasquez
4. Butane the Pyromaniac/???
5. Dr. Octopus/Otto Octavius
6. ???/???
7. The Rhino/Aleksei Sytsevich
8. Speed Demon/James Sanders
9. The Chameleon/Dmitri Smerdyakov

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not May Parker

Comment: One character I'm still wondering about is Alonzo "Lonnie" Lincoln/Tombstone. He's the only character named on the [Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki page](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Freshman_Year) that I haven't spotted in any of the related artwork yet. I'm making the bold assumption that character #6 is not him, since they look nothing like the [comicbook version](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Alonzo_Lincoln_(Earth-616)).

Comment: Unless they've been gender-bent. There's a bunch of that going on in the comics

Comment: I am working on the assumption that they're using a female version of the Unicorn. However, Lonnie Lincoln is not only male in the comics, but also an albino. [This article](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/marvel-studios-animation-panel-recap-x-men-what-if-live/) names a 'Carmella Black' as one of the villains. Perhaps that's meant to be _Carmilla_ Black [from the comics](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Carmilla_Black_(Earth-616)), but character #6 doesn't look much like her either.

Comment: Given the looks, I would have guessed that would be [The Scorcher](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Steven_Hudak_(Earth-616)). introduce d in 1995's _Untold Tales of Spider-Man_ as one of his retroactively first supervillain foes.

Comment: @notovny - Are you referring to character #6 or #4? I don't think the Scorcher's design looks much like either. He does use flamethrowers, like character #4, but that's the only point of similarity. Also, several articles, such as [this](https://www.ign.com/articles/spider-man-freshman-year-arrives-on-disney-in-2024-will-feature-charlie-coxs-daredevil) and [this](https://www.cinemablend.com/superheroes/spider-man/disneys-spider-man-freshman-year-has-revealed-charlie-coxs-daredevil-and-a-ton-of-other-marvel-characters), have stated that one of the villains is called 'Butane the Pyromaniac'.